# GeoServer Error 500 Javax.servlet.ServletException

Tags: geoserver, java

I installed GeoServer 2.22.2 and Java 17 as recommended. I have connected and the  admin functions  is available, but if I want to acced in the servers status, there is error HTTP ERROR 500 Javax.servletException:  See the screenshot joint.
Have  you suggestion? Is this problem of Java?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Nope, not as recommended, Java 17 support is *experimental* in GeoServer. You can use it, but you'll have to delete the Marlin rasterizer, as documented here:

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/java.html#running-on-java-17

Comment: Thanks, i have unstalled java 17 for JAVA 11 and it's work.

Comment: Maybe there should be a link to that document in https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/installation/index.html#installation.